# how I can cut border joining of a view in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm developing an app in React Native. In the app we have a gradient button with bottom-left and top-right corner cut. I have no Idea how to implement that.  Provide me some example or any hints to implement this. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You may find this helping - https://codedaily.io/tutorials/The-Shapes-of-React-Native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clip-path` property which tells what part to be shown in an element using the `polygon()` function to create a hexagon corners. Below code should do the trick.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#522d5b',
    clipPath: `polygon(0 0, 83% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 19% 100%, 0 79%)`
  }
});
```

To play around with the exact values of the corners, you can refer [this link to create clip paths](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)